# How to use many dimensionFilter in Spatie Laravel Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics-api, laravel-10

This example 2 Filters
When i use this 2 filter structure,and what happends is that only the last filter is read by system / eventName

`$data = Analytics::get(
period: Period::create($startDate, $endDate),
metrics: ['eventCount'],
dimensions: ['pagePath','eventName','day','month','linkText','linkClasses','linkUrl'],
// orderBy: [OrderBy::metric('pagePath', true)],
maxResults: 1000,
// offset: 0,
dimensionFilter:  new FilterExpression(
[
'filter' =>  new Filter([
'field_name' => 'pagePath',
'string_filter' => new StringFilter([
'match_type' => MatchType::EXACT,
'value' => '/example/abc',
]),
]),
'filter' =>  new Filter([
'field_name' => 'eventName',
'string_filter' => new StringFilter([
'match_type' => MatchType::EXACT,
'value' => 'click',
]),
]),
]
),
keepEmptyRows:true

```
    );`
```

how to use more than one / many dimensionFilter ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use **setAndGroup** or **setOrGroup** on the filter you're passing in order group other filters, by passing a FilterExpressionList containing the filters to use.

```
    $filter1 = new FilterExpression([
        'filter' => new Filter([
            'field_name' => 'pagePath',
            'string_filter' => new StringFilter([
                'match_type' => MatchType::EXACT,
                'value' => '/example/abc',
            ]),
        ]),
    ]);

    $filter2 = new FilterExpression([
        'filter' => new Filter([
            'field_name' => 'eventName',
            'string_filter' => new StringFilter([
                'match_type' => MatchType::EXACT,
                'value' => 'click',
            ]),
        ]),
    ]);

    $filterList = (new FilterExpressionList())->setExpressions([$filter1, $filter2]);
    $dimensionFilter = (new FilterExpression())->setAndGroup($filterList);
```

Then you can pass the $dimensionFilter variable to the Analytics::get(....) call